# It takes too much reputation to quickly close a thread

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

It currently takes 3000 reputation to close a thread and there are only 15 people who aren't moderators who have 3000+ reputation points.

I thought the premise of the Stack sites was that they're for the people by the people. With the bar set so high, we rely on moderators making the decisions.

If we could lower this limit to 2000 points, we'd have an additional 16 people who can vote this way. If we lowered it to 1500 there would be another 7 people.

1500 points is still a very strong sigh that a user is committed to the site and remember that it would still take multiple users to close/open anything so that would cut down on abuse.

Answer (score 3):

If you feel very strongly that a question should be closed, **flag it for moderator attention!**

[image]

Flags are escalated to moderators and shown in their top navigation very promimently.

Comment: Hi Jeff. Surely you recognise that this fixed system can't work as designed to for all sites. The system that relies on there being "at least x users" online to keep it moderated (without the moderators). Newer sites need lower boundaries. You did it for the big three as they grew up, and the StackExchange sites initially, so why the change of heart?

Answer (score 1):

I think we're doing okay at the closing threads, in cases where there aren't enough votes I've flagged the post and they get taken care of quickly. This is I think why we've been so [worried about voting](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/740/how-can-we-motivate-the-community-to-vote-more), but it appears we're about average for a stack site.

I think we're mostly over this hump as long as people with higher rep continue to be vigilant. I suspect that by Ubuntu's Beta release when we get a surge of new people that we'll be in good shape.

Comment: You can count me out. I came sometimes to answer or vote on questions, but I'm far from vigilant. I lose lots of question between visits, and don't usually check for closing votes. I'm likely not alone, so there are fewer than 15 members who active police this.